# ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS with two .htaccess and a folder /public

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a problem with my .htaccess. My redirections work fine on my machine (localhost), but when i upload my site on my server, the first page works but after being redirect many times, but when i click on links, i have a ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS message.

My folders are organized like that :

```
.htaccess (1)
    /public
    .htaccess (2)
    index.php
```

This is my fist htaccess (1)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*) /public/$1 [L]
```

This is my second htaccess (2)

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
Options -Indexes
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: The first redirect is for a .js file, and then, multiple redirections to my error controller

Comment: Sorry, it was just a problem with the function file_exists, on my machine, the function dosen't matter about uppercase, and on the server the function take care of uppercase and lowercase .. So my application try to redirect to my error controller, but it can't find it

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved,

The problem wasn't with the .htacess file, but with the function file_exists who take care about uppercase on my server but not on my machine.